# Rating the output of a power supply

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

I am making a regulated power supply for guitar pedals similar to the following schematic:
[image]

Instead of having several outlets I have only one, that switches between 9v and 18v.

I was told that by basic rule, when designing a power supply, to accomplish 18v DC and 300mA, I need a transformer rated at 18.2v AC and 600mA.

I want to know what is the max electric current I can supply at each voltage? (9v and 18v). Is it 300mA in both cases, or they are different?

Comment: The text of your question is poorly composed and making it nearly impossible understand what you are asking. It is also hard to decipher what you do know about voltage and current ratings and what you do not.

Comment: I would not make power outlets made to supply power to devices of two different voltage ratings be switchable as you propose. It is just to easy for mistakes to be made and cause damage to either the power supply unit or the pedal units. Make a unit that has two sets of outputs, one at the 9V and the other at the 18V.

Comment: I think you think you were clear. But to me, you aren't. Are you trying to design a new power supply that will provide a switchable output voltage which, either way, would be rated for \$300\:\textrm{mA}\$ compliance current? Or do you already have something you want to understand better? Or what, exactly. I see a schematic with \$12\:\textrm{V}\$ output. I see you asking about design rules. I see you then asking about maximum current given two voltages, which makes me wonder if you already have something. What exactly is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I just edited the question to see if it is clearer.

Comment: I'll try to be clearer. I have already built a power supply with that schematic. I made it so that I have 9v, and by changing the Vadj resistor, I can also get 18v. My question is, if the Current it can provide at the output is the same if I regulate to 9v or if I do so to 18v. For example, if it is 18v 300mA, is it also 9v 300mA since they use the same transfomer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've built a linear regulator, max output current is limited by, 1st: Transformer and 2nd: adjustable regulator IC. So, it will be the same even if the output voltage varies.

In a roughly approximation, some of the current drawn from transformer goes to ground through filter cap *(1000\$\mu\$F after bridge rectifier)* and the rest goes to the load. And generally, in a well-filtered linear regulator, rms current drawn from transformer is approximately 2 times the DC load current, means that if your transformer has a maximum output current rating of 600mA then maximum DC output current will be 300mA even if the output voltage varies.

Note that the maximum output voltage can be (with a fair margin) \$V_{DC}=V_{secondary} \cdot 1.35\$. So, for 18VDC output, you need a transformer with a secondary voltage of 14Vac.

PS: Paralleled output approach is not good for guitar effect pedals because it causes ground loops, and so hum.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I had this doubt because some power supplies from pedal manufacturers state that in their switchable outlets, when they increase the voltage, the current supplied decreases. For example: http://www.t-rex-effects.com/fueltank-chameleon/

Comment: It doesn't make sense for me why they state this, but I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: A small transformer can be fitted with two windings, connected in parallel for low voltage high current, or in series for high voltage at lower current.   That would explain the current rating changing with the voltage switch.

Comment: @Whit3rd Actually no. It comes from "maximum output/input power". They are switching power supplies having output power limiting by sensing and limiting primary (i.e. input) current. If output power is, say, 10W then the input power will be approx. 12W. If you change the output voltage then since the input power limiting remains the same, max output power will change in opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

One factor to consider is the power dissipation in the regulator, and the resulting temperature rise.  Even though the transformer / rectifier can supply the same current at 9V regulator output as it can at 18V output, the regulator power dissipation will be greater when the output is 9V (power dissipation = (Vin - Vout) * current).  Make sure that your regulator will not get too hot when the output is 9V and all your loads are connected.  Then the regulator temperature will be fine when you have 18V out.

Comment: I will keep the power dissipation issue in mind when choosing the heatsink. Thanks for the answer!